# angular material reading colors from external source

Tags: angular, themes, material-design, angular-material2

I have certain themes declared in my theme.scss as follows:

```
$custom-primary: mat-palette($mat-blue-grey,500);
$custom-accent:  mat-palette($mat-light-blue, A200);
$custom-warn:    mat-palette($mat-red);
$custom-theme: mat-light-theme($custom-primary, $custom-accent, $custom-warn);

@include angular-material-theme($custom-theme);
@include widget-theme($custom-theme);

//Orange theme
$ora-primary: mat-palette($mat-orange, 800);
$ora-accent:  mat-palette($mat-deep-purple, A100);
$ora-warn:    mat-palette($mat-red);
$ora-theme: mat-light-theme($ora-primary, $ora-accent);

.orange-theme {
    @include angular-material-theme($ora-theme);
    @include widget-theme($ora-theme);
}

//green theme
$green-primary: mat-palette($mat-green, 800);
$green-accent:  mat-palette($mat-teal, A700);
$green-warn:    mat-palette($mat-red);
$green-theme: mat-light-theme($green-primary, $green-accent);

.green-theme {
    @include angular-material-theme($green-theme);
    @include widget-theme($green-theme);
}
```

As of now i let user switch to a theme by setting value of them as orange-theme or green-theme

```
this.overlayContainer.getContainerElement().classList.add(theme);
```

This works great but limiting as i have to define 10 themes to support 10 variations. What i want is rather few canned themes like above but also ability for the end user to create his own theme by picking a primary and accent color. how can that work?